# Make letters appear on the same line instead of each appearing on its own line

Tags: python

My Code So Far:

```
import random
import time
a = open("settings.txt", "r")
b = open("settings.txt", "a")
adding = input("Enter Name: ")
with open("settings.txt", "a") as f:
     f.write('\n'.join(str(i) for i in adding))
data = a.readlines()
print (data)
time.sleep(10)
```

My settings.txt file:

```
(empty)
```

When I run the code:

```
Enter Name: John
['Blah 1\n', 'Blah 2\n', 'Blah 3\n', 'J\n', 'o\n', 'h\n', 'n']
```

My setting.txt file after i have ran the code:

```
J
o
h
n
```

My Problem:
I am trying to write a code which will allow me to write a name or a general word and then it would write/edit the txt file (settings.txt). When i enter a name/word all the letters of the name/word (in this case john) appear all on different lines. I want them to appear on one line (not spread over four lines but all on one line). How would I do that? Moreover when i print whatever is on the txt file (settings.txt) it as a '\n' after every line. How would I go about removing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this.

```
adding = input("Enter Name: ")

with open("settings.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(adding)

with open("settings.txt", "r") as fp:
    print(fp.readlines())
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through the `adding`, character by character, and writing each of them in a separate line. You should simply write `adding` as it is

```
f.write(adding)
```

**Edit:** To write the current name in a new line, you can use `format` method like this

```
f.write("\n{}".format(adding))
```

Comment: Okay i will try that now!

Comment: Thank you very much it worked! But now the problem is that it just becomes one word not on separate lines. 
my settings.txt file after 'f.write(adding)'
SagarJohn

Comment: How do i make it so each time they enter something it writes it on a different line? because when i had done 'f.write(adding)' then it carried on with the previous word that was in there. e.g before:'john' after 'johnjohn' ?

Comment: That worked great but now it has a /n after ever list item? How do i get rid of that?
Enter Name: Lacey
['Sagar\n', 'John\n', 'Lacey']

Comment: @PythonBeginner `data = [line.rstrip() for line in a.readlines()]`

Comment: Thank you very very much! I am coder for about 3 months now so i thought i would learn about harder things! Thank You! It works a charm!(interested in computers and coding for that matter:P) :DD

Comment: I will! Thank You Very Much Once Again!

Comment: @PythonBeginner Hey, a little while ago I took a free online course, https://www.udacity.com/course/cs101, and found it fantastic, check it out if you can. Good luck.

Comment: I surely will! Thanks for the heads up! Have a nice evening/day/afternoon/morning depending on where you from:P Thanks again!